# ¿cómo hacer una función que al presionar un número ejecute una acción? Kotlin o Java (android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

estoy haciendo una app para android TV, y quisiera crear la funcionalidad en la que el usuario presione los números del control remoto y sea llevado al canal con ese ID. Alguién podría ayudarme? .. Muchas gracias

Este es un código que me funciona, pero con las teclas de navegación... Lo que quiero es que si el usuario pone el 1 vaya al canal con el id 1, si pone el 10 el canal con el id 10 y así sucesivamente... Espero hacerme entender.

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN -> {
             //acá pongo código que me llama el canal anterior y funciona sin problema
                true
            }
            else -> super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
        }
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte puedes poner el codigo que has intentado para hacer lo que necesitas también te recomiendo veas [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ya que como formulas tu pregunta podría ser cerrada debido a que no has puesto lo que has intentado

Comment: Es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.